# How can cart table associate with another table?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I have table table_name(id, cart_token, data , created_at, updated_at ) that wants to associate with shopware cart table using token column (table_name.cart_token = cart.token).

How can we do this association using DAL as long as cart table doesn't have a CartEntity and CartDefinition.

For example: Select * from table_name leftjoin cart on table_name.cart_token=cart.token where cart.token=null.

Comment: Are you getting many carts at the same time? Then you might need to write the full query in raw SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a definition and accompanying entity class you simply won't be able to retrieve the cart as a mapped object using the DAL. You could add your own definition and entity for the `cart` table but I wouldn't recommend it, as this would just cause problems if multiple extensions got the same idea. I would recommend injecting `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` in a service of your plugin and just fetching the cart using raw SQL.

```php
class CartFetcherService
{
    private Connection $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function fetchCart(YourCustomEntity $entity): ?array
    {
        $cart = $this->connection->fetchAssociative(
            'SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `token` = :token',
            [
                'token' => $entity->getToken(),
            ]
        );

        return $cart ?: null;
    }
}
```

If you want to retrieve the `Cart` object directly, you could also inject the `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartPersister` service to load the cart.

```php
class CartLoaderService
{
    private CartPersister $persister;

    public function __construct(CartPersister $persister)
    {
        $this->persister = $persister;
    }

    public function getCart(YourCustomEntity $entity, SalesChannelContext $context): ?Cart
    {
        try {
            $cart = $this->persister->load($entity->getToken(), $context)
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            $cart = null;
        }

        return $cart;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the cart table not have a definition & entity class?

Comment: Because you're not meant to persist data directly to the cart table. There's business logic involved with the cart like the calculation of shipping costs, evaluation of rules for prices, promotions and so on. If the cart was like any other entity developers could be inclined to persist data directly to the cart, circumventing the business logic. By making it not accessible through the DAL developers should be encouraged to use the proper services like the `CartService` instead to make changes to the cart.

Comment: @dneustadt so I assume its also absolutely not possible to get the cart data inside of an appscript because of the missing entity?