# fetching cart data on login page in shopware app

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

in our app we are trying to get the cart data on the login/register page (@Storefront/storefront/component/account/register.html.twig).

the following is what we are doing right now:

```
{% set page = hook.page %}
{# @var page Shopware\Storefront\Page\Account\Login\AccountLoginPageLoadedHook #}
enter code here
{% set criteria = {
'token': [ context.token ],
} %}
{% set myCart = services.repository.search('cart', criteria) %}
{% do page.addArrayExtension('swagMyAdditionalData', myCart) %}
```

we took most of it from https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/data-loading#adding-data-to-the-page-object

we get an error:

> "Execution of script "account-login-page-loaded/add-cart-data-script.twig" for Hook "account-login-page-loaded" failed with message: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Definition for entity "cart" does not exist.") in account-login-page-loaded/add-cart-data-script.twig at line 11."

how can we access the cart data here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cart has no entity definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73910336/8556259). Since the hook in question doesn't [make the cart service available](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference#cart-manipulation), you currently won't be able to access the cart within an app script for this hook.