# Shopware cart repository name

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm having trouble retrieving data from the cart repository in my code. When I try to access the cart repository using `const cartRepository = this.repositoryFactory.create('cart');`, I encounter the following error:

```
An error was captured in the current module: Error: [EntityDefinitionRegistry] No definition found for entity type 'cart'.
```

Below is my complete code:

```
import template from './cartCancelRate.html.twig';
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;

Shopware.Component.register('cartCancelRate', {
    template,
    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory',
        'stateStyleDataProviderService',
        'acl',
    ],

    data() {
        return {
            cancelRate: 0
        };
    },

    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            const cartRepository = this.repositoryFactory.create('cart');

            const criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.addFilter(
                this.criteriaFactory.range(
                    'createdAt',
                    { lt: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0] } // Excluding today's date
                )
            );

            cartRepository.search(criteria, Shopware.Context.api).then((result) => {
                const cartCount = result.total;

                // Get the total number of orders
                const orderRepository = this.repositoryFactory.create('order');
                orderRepository.search(criteria, Shopware.Context.api).then((orderResult) => {
                    const orderCount = orderResult.total; // Total number of orders

                    // Calculate cancel rate
                    this.cancelRate = cartCount / orderCount;
                });
            });
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchData()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cart table has no entity definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73910336/8556259) and therefore also no attached repository. In the administration you could inject `cartStoreService` and call [`getCart`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/service/api/cart-store-api.api.service.ts#L34) but you will need the specific context token, which you will likely not have at hand.

It might be best to take a look at the [`SalesChannelProxyController`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/Api/Controller/SalesChannelProxyController.php#L220) which is requested by the service. You could implement your own admin-API endpoint where you could fetch data directly from the `cart` table using an injected instance of `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`. Keep in mind though, that this is not data meant to be accessed directly, hence why there is no repository. You're supposed to use the appropriate abstractions for the carts that handle calculations and such. So what you might want to do is fetch the tokens from `sales_channel_api_context` and use them to get the properly calculated carts. Regarding performance impacts, this would only lend itself to a detailed view of a single cart and not to an entire listing of carts though. What you could ultimately do is to fetch all carts directly  from the table for the listing and then have a detail view that uses `cartStoreService` to get the properly calculated cart via the token.